# html query on recent sites listed

Tags: html

I want to know how the following is done.
When using the weather station site - [Wunderground.com](http://www.wunderground.com/), the page displays a list of the recent weather stations that you visited. This is found just under the page banner.
The only script (coding) in the source that I can find related to the `Recent cities` title is -

```
<div id="recentCities">
    Recent Cities:
    <a href="/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:00000.1.68842">Port Elizabeth, ZA</a>
    |
    <a href="/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:00000.1.68456">Qacha's Nek, LS</a>
</div>
```

How can I place such a function onto a webpage that I am developing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using a cookie to store data about the user (probably with a session and possibly with a user account). A list of previous pages visited on the site can be in that data.

This could be implemented using any kind of server side programming.

The URLs you use suggest that the interface between the server and the server side program is CGI.